# Tensor shape does not make sense to me after using `batch()` on dataset

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

Here is my code to test tf.data.Dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# build a random tensor
x=tf.random_uniform([10, 10])
# transform to dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x)
# batch reading   
dataset = dataset.batch(3)
ite = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
ele = ite.get_next()

sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(ite.initializer)
ele_ = sess.run(ele)
print ele_.shape
```

The program outputs a shape of `[1,10,10]` not `[3,10,10]` which totally makes no sense to me.

Anyone can help to explain this ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensors), `from_tensors` creates a dataset with a single element from the given input. That is, you are creating a dataset with one element of shape `[10, 10]`.
Since you only have one element, `batch` can only create a one-element batch, giving a new dataset that contains one element of shape `[1, 10, 10]`.

Maybe you are looking for `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`? In this case, this would create a dataset of 10 elements, each of shape `[10]`. Then, applying `batch(3)` would actually give you batches of 3, i.e. elements of shape `[3, 10]` (except for the leftover batch that only has one element).

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. I don't understand the doc, say `Creates a Dataset whose elements are slices of the given tensors`. Does it mean it will create `10` tensors each with shape `[10]` ?

Comment: If we index the `10` tensors of shape `[10]` as 0,1,2,3...9 and apply `batch(3)`. Finally iterator will give you tensors indexed by 0, 1, 2 for the first `run()`, then 3, 4, 5 for the second `run()`, and so on so force. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it will be rows 0,1,2, then 3,4,5, then 6,7,8 and then 9, so the last batch will be smaller. If you pass `drop_remainder=True`to `batch` then row 9 will not be returned at all.

Comment: Pretty helpful. Thanks!